# How can I load a list from a async function into a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to connect to a database and perform a query which returns a list. I would like to load that list into my Flutter app but I am confused on how to do this. This is my current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'YOURCHAT',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 7,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to load the data into the body in a text widget.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Future builder correctly

```
//The function which calls data from database

Future functionName() async {
  var result = await http.get('url');
  Chats data = [];
  decodeResult = json.decode(result);
  for (d in decodeResult){
    data = (d["your db column"]: title, d["your db column"]: subtitle)
}
return data;
}
```

```
//The class for variables

Class Chats(
    String title,
    String subtitle,
   ({this.title, this.subtitle})
)
```

Updated your body section

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(

    child: Futurebuilder(
         future: functionName,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snashot){
         return  Listview.builder(
           builder: (BuildContext contex, int index){
           if (snapshot.hasData){
     return ListTile(
        title: Text(snapshot.data.title),
        subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.subtitle)
);
}
);
}
)
)
```